# Getting FileNotFound exception on android 11

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11

Trying to fetch whatsapp statuses files. Some files are accessible but some are throwing FileNotfound Exception on Android 11, Even all files are there in the .Statuses folder.

Step 1: I have gained permission(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) of statuses folder

```
final String ANDROID_DOCID = "primary:"+whatsApp_root_path;
final String EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.android.externalstorage.documents";
private Uri androidUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, ANDROID_DOCID);
private Uri androidTreeUri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, ANDROID_DOCID);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, androidUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
```

Step 2: In onActivityResult I am fetching files by using DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri)

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
DocumentFile documentFile1 = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
        DocumentFile[] fileList = documentFile1.listFiles();
        Uri documentFileUri = null;
        for (DocumentFile documentFile:fileList) {
            documentFileUri = documentFile.getUri();
            if(documentFileUri.toString().contains(".Statuses")){
                MyLog.d("\nSTATUSES uri" + documentFileUri.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
        DocumentFile documentStatusesFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, documentFileUri);
        if(documentStatusesFile != null){
            DocumentFile[] statusesFiles = documentStatusesFile.listFiles();
            MyLog.d("\nSTATUSES uris START");
            for (DocumentFile statusFile :statusesFiles) {
                Uri statusUri = statusFile.getUri();
                MyLog.d("\nuri :"+statusUri.toString());
                Uri mediaUri = null;
                try{
                    mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(CommonApp.getContext(), statusUri);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }
```

**MediaStore.getMediaUri() - Getting exception on this line**

*Exception is : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No item at content://media/external_primary/file*

Comment: `MediaStore` does not index that content, presumably.

Comment: Then why is this not true for all the files in that directory. As I mentioned in issue description that some files are accessible via Mediastore and some are not.

Comment: I have no idea what ones are accessible and what ones are not, so I cannot comment on that. Bear in mind that you might not have access to any of this content on Android 12+.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even If I prompt user to provide permission for perticular directory ?

Comment: But why do you want a mediastore uri too? You did not explain that.

Comment: @blackapps I want mediastore uri because I want to get some properties of file which are not available in DocumentFile like Resolution, Relative Path, Duration(For Video file), Added date, Modified date etc.

Comment: "Even If I prompt user to provide permission for perticular directory ?" -- that does not change whether `MediaStore` indexes the content. And, you are assuming that the user can grant you permission to that directory, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @CommonsWare then how can I get all above mentioned properties of a file through Document File object?

Comment: You already know the relative path. There is no added date, but you can use [`lastModified()` on `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#lastmodified) to attempt to get a modified date (bearing in mind that it does not have to be correct). Details about media can be retrieved [via `MediaMetadataRetriever`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever).

Comment: I tried to fetch properties via MediaMetaDataRetriever but it was also throwing exception.   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No item at content://media/external_primary/file

Comment: @CommonsWare any solution?

Comment: Make sure that you are using [the `setDataSource()` that takes a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)). Otherwise, consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] of what you are using for `MediaMetadataRetriever` and the complete stack trace of your error.